# driver.switch_to.alert.text throws exepction: no such alerts but there is an alert

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver, web-scraping, selenium-chromedriver

I'm trying to open a https://drive.inditex.com/drfrcomr/login with Selenium.

It opens a prompt with username and password fields, & submit and cancel buttons. I am trying to close the prompt. It can be closed by clicking the cancel button or clicking the escape key.

Note: ignore irrelevant imports please

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.alert import Alert
from selenium.webdriver import Chrome 
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.service import Service 
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By 
from webdriver_manager.chrome import ChromeDriverManager
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
from selenium.webdriver.common.action_chains import ActionChains

options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
options.headless = False
options.page_load_strategy = 'none' 
chrome_path = ChromeDriverManager().install() 
chrome_service = Service(chrome_path)
driver = Chrome(options=options, service=chrome_service) 
driver.implicitly_wait(5)

url = "https://drive.inditex.com/drfrcomr/sales/home?brand=2" 
driver.get(url)

print("printing alert text:", driver.switch_to.alert.text)
ActionChains(driver).send_keys(Keys.ESCAPE).perform()
```

The WebDriver is not picking the prompt box.

Comment: I don't see any alert, simply a fairly standard login page.  What device/browser are you using?

Comment: without registered account your error is not reproducible

Comment: I'm using Chrome browser. @Easty77

Comment: @Ronin You don't need any account in this case. You just need to click cancel button

Comment: there is no cancel button https://ibb.co/84wP4x8

Comment: @Ronin open it with Chrome browser. I think you're opening it with firefox or something else. Also use PC, not mobile.